# LVM partition as "physical" disk for VMware Player

Tags: vmware-player, lvm

I would like to make a VMware Player virtual machine, where the disk would be stored on an LVM partition. I'd like to have the virtual disk contents stored on raw LVM logical volume, and not as a file on some host filesystem. I hope to make it faster this way.

I tried to do that, but I get permission problems:

> Cannot open the disk
>   '/home/me/vm/physical.vmdk' or one of
>   the snapshot disks it depends on.
>   Reason: Insufficient permission to
>   access file.

I did `chown me:me /dev/dm-4` (where /dev/dm-4 is the logical volume I want to use), but this doesn't help.

Is it possible at all? If so, how to do this?

Host: Debian Sid, VMware Player 3.1.0.